# How to display images picked from File Picker in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In a Flutter web app, I would like to allow user to select multiple images using file_picker package, display selected images, then upload to server.

```
List<MultipartFile> files = [];

Future<void> PickUploadFiles(context) async {
  FilePickerResult? result = await await FilePicker.platform
      .pickFiles(allowMultiple: true, type: FileType.image);
  if (result != null) {
    files = result.files
        .map((file) => MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'file', file.bytes as List<int>,
      filename: file.name,
    )).toList();
  } else {
// User canceled the picker
  }
}
```

I can show the filenames by:
print(files[0].filename);
print(files[1].filename);
which means they are successfully stored in the list of MultipartFile.

The question is how can I display the content as a list of Image in the UI.

P.S. .path is not accessible in web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use bytes stored in `MultiPartFile` to display an image using `Image.memory` constructor from `Image` widget.

1. Instead of `List<MultipartFile> files = []`, do `List<PlatformFile> files = [];` because this allows you to access bytes. You can also have multipart files if you need them for something else.

```dart
List<PlatformFile> files = []; 
List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles = []; // only use if you need it. You can move to the place where you actually need it.

Future<void> PickUploadFiles(context) async {
  FilePickerResult? result = await await FilePicker.platform
      .pickFiles(allowMultiple: true, type: FileType.image);
  if (result != null) {
    files = result.files;
    multipartFiles = result.files
        .map((file) => MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      'file', file.bytes as List<int>,
      filename: file.name,
    )).toList();
  } else {
// User canceled the picker
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: files.length,
    builder: (context, index) {
      final file = files[index];
      return Image.memory(file.bytes);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Birju, but there is no file.bytes
Error: The getter 'bytes' isn't defined for the class 'MultipartFile'

Comment: @TonyLam I see. I have updated my answer!

Comment: @Thanks Birju, it works now!